# c++: How to read the first number of each line of an input file and ignore the rest

Tags: c++

Say I have an input file text.txt that looks like this:

**12.4**         Mass           kg

**32**          acceleration   m/s^2

**21**          volume         m^3

I would like to get the first number in each row and use it as a variable and ignore the rest of the line.

Thanks!

Comment: Look up [istream::ignore](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/ignore).

Comment: Are you sure you want to ignore the rest of the line, because that is how you would know what variable the number represents...

Answer (score 0):

Try the following

```
#include <limits>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

//...

double d;

while ( file_stream >> d )
{
    file_stream.ignore( std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n' );
}
```